Type error when specifying a single key and value in an object
I have a table of values. Clicking on a value, puts the value in a textfield. The updated value is saved onBlur. A state is used to save the current edit.
type Row = {
    id: number
    name1: string
    name2: string
}

type EditState_InProgress = {
    id: number
    name: 'name1' | 'name2'
    value: string
}

type EditState = EditState_InProgress

const onBlur = (params: EditState_InProgress) => {
    // type error
    updateField({id: params.id, [params.name]: params.value})
    // works fine
    updateRow({id: params.id, [params.name]: params.value})
}

type PartialRow = {id: number, name1: string} | {id: number, name2: string}

const updateField = (partialRowToSave: PartialRow) => {
  // send updated field to server
}

const updateRow = (rowToSave: Partial<Row>) => {
  // send updated row to server
}

The type PartialRow more accurately reflects what is happening, but TypeScript gives the error:
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string | number; id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialRow'.
  Property 'name2' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string | number; id: number; }' but required in type '{ id: number; name2: string; }'.

Here is the example on TypeScript playground:
Will someone please explain why the error occurs and how to fix it?

Using const editParam = { [editState.name]: editState.value, } as AfterEditParams; seems to make the Typescript error go away, but I've no idea if this is what you are trying to accomplish. What is saveEdit going to do with editParam? Also, your reducer pattern is a bit odd; typically the action would be an object with a type property to use for the switch cases, and an optional payload property value to use in the cases. Can you [edit] to clarify the goal you are trying to accomplish, providing a more complete [mcve] if necessary?
